# how to display editor text which is come from the database in react native?

Tags: react-native

I want to display a simple editor content which is come from my database in JSON format. what should I do use?
I just only display this content.
please help me. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

from your question it appears that you want to display text from your json object

```
const TextObject = JSON.parse(jsonObject);

return (
<View >
        <Text>{TextObject}</Text>
</View>
```